# Did Maxwell discuss charge quantization?

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, 19th-century, maxwell

I once read in Wikipedia that James Clerk Maxwell included the possibility that charge could be both quantified and continuous. Since the electron hadn't been discovered in 1873, does Maxwell discuss this anywhere in his 1873 book$^\color{red}{\star}$ or in any other of his publications? If so, where?

---

<sub>$\color{red}{\star}$ James Clerk Maxwell, [A treatise on electricity and magnetism](https://archive.org/details/electricandmagne01maxwrich/page/n20/mode/2up?q=Amp%C3%A8re), 1873.</sub>